# JavaScript A variable assigning itself to itself is causing problems in my code when I run it

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment for class, and the instructor has informed us, here is a book, here is a website, I want you to do this by this date and if you fail its not my fault.  I have looked in the website, the book, and several places on stackOverflow but I don't think I've seen a problem like this come up that's been explained well enough for me to troubleshoot my way out of it in time for the turn in on Wednesday at noon (UTC -5).

I have a mockup of a registration form as an HTML page (not even HTML5, please don't ask) Here is the code for that.

```js
function bucc_registration()
{
 //THE FOLLOWING ALERT IS FOR TROUBLESHOOTING PURPOSES ONLY
 //alert("inside BucC_Registration()");

 //GET THE VALUES FROM THE FORM AND STORE IN THE VARIABLES FOR VALIDATION
 var fullName = document.getElementById("buccFName").value;
 var eMail = document.getElementById("buccEMail").value;
 var phone = document.getElementById("buccPhone").value;
 var pass = document.getElementById("buccPass").value;
 var passConf = document.getElementById("buccPassConf").value;

 //CLEAR OUT ALL OLD MESSAGES AND ERRORS
 document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("error4").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("error5").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "";

 //CHECK ALL VALUES FOR NON-BLANK ENTRIES
 if (fullName == "" || fullName == null || fullName == fullName)
 {
  document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "Please insert your full name.";

  return false;
 }
 
 //ONCE THEY BYPASS THE INPUT TEST, THEN THE VALIDATION TESTS CAN BEGIN

 //fullName NEEDS NO FURTHER VALIDATION
 //eMail NEEDS NO FURTHER VALIDATION

 //VALIDATION FOR PHONE NUMBER TO MAKE SURE IT WAS ENTERED IN THE XXX-XXX-XXXX FORMAT AND AS NUMBERS
 return false;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form id="frm1" onsubmit="return bucc_registration()" action="">
    
   <input type="text" name="buccFName" id="buccFName" /> Full Name &nbsp;<font color="red"><b id="error1"> </b></font><br />
      
   <input type="text" name="buccEMail" id="buccEMail" /> Email &nbsp;<font color="red"><b id="error2"> </b></font><br />
      
   <input type="text" name="buccPhone" id="buccPhone" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" /> Phone &nbsp;<font color="red"><b id="error3"> </b></font><br />
      
   <input type="text" name="buccPass" id="buccPass" /> Password &nbsp;<font color="red"><b id="error4"> </b></font><br />
      
   <input type="text" name="buccPassConf" id="buccPassConf" /> Password Confirmation &nbsp;<font color="red"><b id="error5"> </b></font><br />

   <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Submit"> &nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset">
  </form>
<script src="scripts/BucC_Registration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My problem is that when I run the full code in any browser the JavaScript will fill the variables with blank or user data as it is supposed to.  I tried to leave the user name blank to make sure that the error message would show up properly and that's when trouble started.  It would error out and when I looked into why it wasn't displaying an error it would tell me it was because the variable was holding a value.  Essentially var fullName === fullName; (Yes I did check that, it did work)

I don't know why or how. But I'm fairly certain that once I get this sorted out the other 4 variables that are doing this to me (eMail, pass, and passConf) will stop being a problem.

The current problem is this.  How do I stop a variable from becoming its own... content?  Its almost as if its shadowing and I'm unable to get it to stop on 4 different variables and I didn't do it intentionally.

Comment: why are you checking for `fullName == fullName` ... that's always true (except if `fullName == NaN` of course) which means the condition is always true (that's how OR (||) works)

Comment: Show us where you are assigning a variable to itself. That's not your problem. Are you confusing comparison with assignment?

Comment: I used it to check if it was just fullName == fullName or if it was fullName == "fullName" when I was troubleshooting on my own.  Turned out it was the first.

Comment: `How do I stop a variable from becoming its own... content` ... the content of a variable is only ever one value at any moment, and that value will always equal that value

Comment: I am not assigning the variable to itself  you have all of the current active js code that is in the file at the moment.

Comment: This is why you should use [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) instead of `return false` for events. You would see your javascript has an error (no element with id `feedback`), instead the page reloads or posts because the error causes the returns to never be encountered

Comment: give me a second and i'll grab a screenshot of what I'm looking at

Comment: Is that what that is @PatrickEvans

Comment: It is if the code you have in your snippet is the same that you actually have

Comment: I have to do this my professor's way, I've already been accused of cheating on one test because my code looks a lot like my best friends.  Just trying to survive the semester now.

Comment: http://kcddagger.com/img/js1.jpg

Comment: http://kcddagger.com/img/js2.jpg

Comment: Also strange because I did check my HTML code and I do have an element to go with my feedback ID

Comment: You should really understand and plan before writing the code. For example, there shouldn't be any reason to write `fullName == "" || fullName == null || fullName == fullName`. Trim `fullName`, and then check if `fullName.length === 0`. Also, use CSS for styling instead of `font` and `b`.

Comment: @GrantMiller this is for a class where the professor wants it done his way and if I deviate from his way I get docked points.  His way includes using coding methods from the dark ages.  If I could use CSS for font and b and get out of the class with my GPA over a 2 I would.  The variable == "" || variable == null is also his way.  the || fullName == fullName is me trying to figure out why the heck the fullName is assigning itself to itself and when I did a fullName === fullName it still passed.  I explained the majority of this when I first wrote up the problem.  Is there anything else?

Comment: I don't know if I am being clear.  But when I am saying that fullName is being assigned to fullName.  that is LITERALLY what is happening.  After all the code has finished running and no errors have process that I can see, I inspect (in Chrome) and run it again.  With an empty text input it returns the error that if(fullname) returned true ONLY because fullName was assigned fullName.  If I put my name in the text box that statement will still return true for the same reason.  It will not return my name if I were to put in an output further down the line because the code errors out before then.

Comment: A hugely silly mistake - document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = ""; - This is the culprit. As there is no element with id "feedback"... Comment out this line and the code will work as expected..

Comment: There is an element with that ID.  its just below the form.  Does it need to be IN the form?  if this is the case then that is an easily solvable problem.  when I ran a test message through the errors and the feedback it posted the test message where it should.

Comment: </form>

      <p><font color="red"><b id="feedback"></b></font></p><!--
    to display the feedback from the validation-->
     </section>

Comment: Got it sorted out, a friend in school helped, but even he was scratching his head at what my possessed laptop was doing. (the IT department even calls it possessed LOL)